# # of plays is always null in JSON on API calls?

Tags: json, api, statistics, vimeo

I've tried GET /videos/{videoId}
as well as /videos?query={query}&per_page=1

Both of these return successfully and I am able to see things like title, URL, etc in the JSON, but no matter how I hit the Vimeo API, the stats.plays attribute seems to always be null.  I've tried multiple videos.

I'm using basic authentication with their API.

Here is a sample of the JSON I get back:

```
{"metadata":{"connections":{"comments":{"total":12,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/videos/121647660/comments"},"related":null,"credits":{"total":1,"options":["GET","POST"],"uri":"/videos/121647660/credits"},"texttracks":{"total":0,"options":["GET","POST"],"uri":"/videos/121647660/texttracks"},"pictures":{"total":1,"options":["GET","POST"],"uri":"/videos/121647660/pictures"},"likes":{"total":63,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/videos/121647660/likes"}},"interactions":{"report":{"reason":["pornographic","harassment","advertisement","ripoff","incorrect rating","spam"],"options":["POST"],"uri":"/videos/121647660/report"}}},"upload":null,"link":"https://vimeo.com/zebbler/perceptronium","description":"Audio: Perceptronium - Zebbler Encanti Experience\n(track from Freakquency album) free/pay-what-you-want download here:\nhttp://music.gravitasrecordings.com/track/perceptronium\nmusic written, produced, mixed & mastered by Encanti\nvocal samples by Encanti and Ganavya\n\nVideo:\nStoryline, direction, editing, animation and effects by Zebbler\nCinematography: Zebbler, Norman Magnuson\nGrip: Matt Hargrave\nColor correction by Norman Magnuson\nAdditional effects by Jake Stafford\nAirbrushing: Adam Giangregorio\nCostuming: Charlotte Janowski\nStarring:\nRay Carre\nAdam Giangregorio\nNicole Leland\nCharlotte Janowski\nLionel Waters Semedo\nMaryam Barrows\nPainting by: Andrew Bunyan\nAdditional technical, physical and moral assistance by: Encanti, Andrew Bunyan, Nick Ruhlman, Leah Barrows, Nora Jean McCarthy, Matthew Benincasa, Gordon McPherson, Alex Ezorsky\nProduced by Zebbler Studios: http://zebblerstudios.com\n\nShot at following locations:\nGlitch Gallery, Boston\nKatwise House, NY - http://katwise.com/house.html\nHuge thanks to Katwise for allowing us to use her most amazing psychedelic home and property as a backdrop to our music video.  Please show her some support by buying one of her amazing sweaters:\nhttps://www.etsy.com/shop/katwise","privacy":{"add":true,"view":"anybody","download":true,"comments":"anybody","embed":"public"},"language":null,"review_link":"https://vimeo.com/zebbler/review/121647660/8084e23749","pictures":{"sizes":[{"link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F510198388_100x75.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","width":100,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/510198388_100x75.jpg?r=pad","height":75},{"link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F510198388_200x150.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","width":200,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/510198388_200x150.jpg?r=pad","height":150},{"link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F510198388_295x166.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","width":295,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/510198388_295x166.jpg?r=pad","height":166},{"link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F510198388_640x360.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","width":640,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/510198388_640x360.jpg?r=pad","height":360},{"link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F510198388_960x540.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","width":960,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/510198388_960x540.jpg?r=pad","height":540},{"link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F510198388_1280x720.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","width":1280,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/510198388_1280x720.jpg?r=pad","height":720},{"link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F510198388_1920x1080.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","width":1920,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/510198388_1920x1080.jpg?r=pad","height":1080},{"link_with_play_button":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F510198388_1280x720.jpg&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png","width":1280,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/510198388_1280x720.jpg?r=pad","height":720}],"resource_key":"0bde14b69494effb29a827752b3da99ff0121d37","active":true,"type":"custom","uri":"/videos/121647660/pictures/510198388"},"duration":330,"modified_time":"2018-08-03T03:02:47+00:00","stats":{"plays":null},"content_rating":["language","nudity"],"embed":{"badges":{"weekend_challenge":false,"hdr":false,"vod":false,"staff_pick":{"normal":false,"best_of_the_month":false,"best_of_the_year":false,"premiere":false},"live":{"archived":false,"streaming":false}},"html":"<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/121647660?badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0&app_id=131532\" width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" frameborder=\"0\" title=\"Perceptronium (music video by Zebbler Encanti Experience)\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen><\/iframe>"},"height":720,"release_time":"2015-03-09T07:50:31+00:00","app":{"name":"Dropbox","uri":"/apps/20166"},"created_time":"2015-03-09T07:50:31+00:00","embed_presets":null,"transcode":null,"uri":"/videos/121647660","tags":[{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":120,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/zebbler/videos"}}},"resource_key":"1bf8a8d9f42b2fa64771aa230ffb25de55596388","name":"zebbler","tag":"zebbler","canonical":"zebbler","uri":"/tags/zebbler"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":32,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/zebblerstudios/videos"}}},"resource_key":"902c91e667b48c16ece00693cefd0195bd37a552","name":"zebbler studios","tag":"zebbler studios","canonical":"zebblerstudios","uri":"/tags/zebblerstudios"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":1288,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/zee/videos"}}},"resource_key":"9e714d830673187ad60be64fea43137d62801211","name":"zee","tag":"zee","canonical":"zee","uri":"/tags/zee"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":25,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/zebblerencantiexperience/videos"}}},"resource_key":"f603dca8fcefca57c4d61386a0e76efadcf97227","name":"zebbler encanti experience","tag":"zebbler encanti experience","canonical":"zebblerencantiexperience","uri":"/tags/zebblerencantiexperience"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":61,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/encanti/videos"}}},"resource_key":"4d282f6db0b97ab212a5e9bfec9b34a3c4bad7a8","name":"encanti","tag":"encanti","canonical":"encanti","uri":"/tags/encanti"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":116,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/gravitas/videos"}}},"resource_key":"420b0edef142ec456c406795eea8c12bddf1a9dc","name":"gravitas","tag":"gravitas","canonical":"gravitas","uri":"/tags/gravitas"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":23909,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/psychedelic/videos"}}},"resource_key":"178b11a83003bb451cd84d953fcda37989addf5e","name":"psychedelic","tag":"psychedelic","canonical":"psychedelic","uri":"/tags/psychedelic"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":956579,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/music/videos"}}},"resource_key":"676be0ef6a740f2fb2a63590afae3263618d5212","name":"music","tag":"music","canonical":"music","uri":"/tags/music"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":880210,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/video/videos"}}},"resource_key":"0c021dd5f4d5bdae6f2ae8af39587025ecdbf2e0","name":"video","tag":"video","canonical":"video","uri":"/tags/video"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":13111,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/trap/videos"}}},"resource_key":"82a5f926deeeb51d09ead990e3a20e780434261d","name":"trap","tag":"trap","canonical":"trap","uri":"/tags/trap"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":26183,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/dubstep/videos"}}},"resource_key":"5861b5285defa5021cc97a86888aff0cea5b8922","name":"dubstep","tag":"dubstep","canonical":"dubstep","uri":"/tags/dubstep"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":3902,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/penis/videos"}}},"resource_key":"8674bcb141835f4ab0353b1d434e1cfd1b073c16","name":"penis","tag":"penis","canonical":"penis","uri":"/tags/penis"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":13470,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/nudity/videos"}}},"resource_key":"de95eca3a1be8f13ff29303647bd6588071f1488","name":"nudity","tag":"nudity","canonical":"nudity","uri":"/tags/nudity"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":3,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/katwise/videos"}}},"resource_key":"7ee5a1f304fcd5ef88286aa93e9c3571a97ec529","name":"katwise","tag":"katwise","canonical":"katwise","uri":"/tags/katwise"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":1064,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/sweater/videos"}}},"resource_key":"cdb610feab10ff296d9fe09331ca2d66750d6ab5","name":"sweater","tag":"sweater","canonical":"sweater","uri":"/tags/sweater"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":26167,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/edm/videos"}}},"resource_key":"b623bc599a8dc45d59714399c2409156ab14ba73","name":"edm","tag":"edm","canonical":"edm","uri":"/tags/edm"},{"metadata":{"connections":{"videos":{"total":530,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/tags/malenudity/videos"}}},"resource_key":"2fc23444c07d5d976892fd5514ef11e9843a452a","name":"male nudity","tag":"male nudity","canonical":"malenudity","uri":"/tags/malenudity"}],"license":null,"resource_key":"84f4570eb43aa86123a9bcfa2bc3c483976db623","name":"Perceptronium (music video by Zebbler Encanti Experience)","width":1280,"user":{"created_time":"2008-06-18T12:41:17+00:00","metadata":{"connections":{"shared":{"total":61,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/shared/videos"},"albums":{"total":0,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/albums"},"moderated_channels":{"total":4,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/channels?filter=moderated"},"watchlater":{"total":2,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/watchlater"},"portfolios":{"total":0,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/portfolios"},"groups":{"total":48,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/groups"},"videos":{"total":74,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/videos"},"pictures":{"total":1,"options":["GET","POST"],"uri":"/users/546190/pictures"},"appearances":{"total":5,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/appearances"},"feed":{"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/feed"},"followers":{"total":489,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/followers"},"channels":{"total":12,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/channels"},"activities":{"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/activities"},"following":{"total":33,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/following"},"categories":{"total":0,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/categories"},"likes":{"total":337,"options":["GET"],"uri":"/users/546190/likes"}}},"preferences":{"videos":{"privacy":null}},"resource_key":"9b127ab563bfb387b5eeb1959e3fc98b68147f1a","name":"Zebbler","link":"https://vimeo.com/zebbler","bio":"I am the pixel wizard","location":"Boston","websites":[{"name":null,"link":"http://www.zebbler.com","description":null}],"uri":"/users/546190","pictures":{"sizes":[{"width":30,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/19308747_30x30","height":30},{"width":75,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/19308747_75x75","height":75},{"width":100,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/19308747_100x100","height":100},{"width":300,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/19308747_300x300","height":300},{"width":72,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/19308747_72x72","height":72},{"width":144,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/19308747_144x144","height":144},{"width":216,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/19308747_216x216","height":216},{"width":288,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/19308747_288x288","height":288},{"width":360,"link":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/19308747_360x360","height":360}],"resource_key":"ef85a7a00a05ef1816f61329870a26cb26ca5f59","active":true,"type":"custom","uri":"/users/546190/pictures/19308747"},"account":"plus"},"status":"available"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your token have the `private` scope, and are you trying to pull stats for your own videos? We don't return play stats for videos where the token isn't owned by the video creator.

Comment: My token was created using the **Generate unauthenticated tokens** section on [https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication] .  The default scope is public.  These are not my own videos.  I am attempting to create a link-reader/query bot who can return basic video information and perform basic searches.  I'll try to see if I can add a private scope to my token.  Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately we don't return video stats within the API for unauthenticated tokens.

Comment: OK.  I'll see if I can get an authenticated token working.  I know you probably don't have any control over these sorts of things and maybe there's a valid reason to suppress this information, but I feel like the # of plays on a video is very much a public piece of information.  For applications that just want to have some basic link-reading capabilities, it's a lot of additional effort.  Either way, thank you for the information.

Comment: Had the same issue, and switching to an authenticated token fixed it.